# generate yield for every item in array Generator JS

Tags: javascript, generator

I'm trying to make my generator more flexible

**From this:**

```
function *formValidationSequence () {
    yield someRef.current.func()
    yield someOtherRef.current.func()
    ...
}
```

**To this:**

```
const array = [someRef, someOtherRef]

const handler = (array) => {
    const sequence = testSequence(function *() {
        yield* array.map(item => item.current.func())
    })
}
```

But it doesn't work. I want to create `yield` dynamically for every ref/item in an array, without to call 'em instantly.

How it should be done?

Comment: Why `map`? Why not `for(const el of array) yield el.current.func()`?

Comment: What are the `func()` doing, and what doesn't work?

Comment: @Jonas Wilms Yes, of course!, I don't thought of that. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do

```
 yield* iterable
```

which will create an iterator from the iterable and yield all it's values up. Now your iterable is the thing returned from `.map`, which is an array that already contains all the calculated results. To `yield` every item one after another, you need a `for` loop, as that can be interrupted:

```
 for(const item of [someRef, someOtherRef])
   yield* item.current.func();
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` will execute the function on every item in the array before calling `yield*` on it. If you want to only call one function per iteration, then just use a regular loop:

```js
function*() {
    for (const el of array) {
        yield el.current.func();
    }
}
```